# Stale monitoring errors?

Tags: replication, mongodb, monitoring, mongodb-3.2, ops-manager

After setting a cluster with 3 shards, 3 config server with 2 mongos.

[image]

I see these errors in the monitoring agents    Failure during discovery.

What do they mean I tried to see it on the internet but no luck. [image]

Comment: Does monitoring agent not work? It means you don't have any statistics and performance graphs available for your deployment? If yes paste 10 lines before and after the errors from log file `monitoring-agent.log`. Please also paste the `mms-automation-agent.log` from the host in question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer came in with adding a documents into the seetings collection inside the config database.

syntax:

```
use config

show collections

db.settings.insert({ "_id" : "chunksize", "value" : NumberLong(64) })

db.setting.find()           ---#to check
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From those error messages, I can see that there is "name resolution" problem. Like dcixcfitrmdbs03.dcicloud.local what points to "localhost" address obviously.

Comment: Inserting the below line in the db.settings worked.